# Automation framework for testing lamda on aws

Tags: automated-testing

Does anyone know how to test serverless lambda on aws?
Basically, to get input and output file, but not with lambda console.
So for architecture it is SQS from aws sending messages on lambda, and labda is transferring them to DB.

I want to test lambda, like first part, and then integrate more maybe on DB.

Comment: can you elaborate more? As AWS Java SDK allows to interact with AWS.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: I don't know about a proper framework but why not use a mocked DB and tie everything together with any test framework you are used to?

Comment: @Rsf Let say the DB is not problematic it will live in all env. (in our case in Testing env). More problematic is SQS message sending.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the aws documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/testing-functions.html

You can test your Lambda function in the console by invoking your function with a test event. A test event is a JSON input to your function. If your function doesn't require input, the event can be an empty document ({})